# In laravel livewire, I want to get the user only if it's value changed from specific value to another specific value

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Here is the code in which I get the user if it's `g10_eng_unwh` is equal to `1`.

```
public function purchased(User $user)
{
     if ($user->g10_eng_unwh == 1) {
         $token = "g10_eng_unwh";
     }
     if ($user->g7_eng_unwh == 1) {
         $token = "g7_eng_unwh";
     }
     $time = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
     dd($user->email, $time, $token);
}
```

Instead, I want to get the user only when it's `g10_eng_unwh` value changes from 0 to 1.
Is there any way?

Comment: but you want to get the user through a query or on the model update listening to that event?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the past value at the beginning so that you can apply the condition, it will have to be stored somewhere. Most likely you will need to create `g10_eng_unwh_old` or something like that. I assume that `g10_eng_unwh` is a column in the database, in this case create `g10_eng_unwh_old` and store the old value in it.

In this case, you could get it even on request. For example

```
DB::query()
 ->where('g10_eng_unwh', 1)
 ->where('g10_eng_unwh_old', 0)
 ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved it as you said.